# unexpected character after line continuation character in SimpleGraphics

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw a diagonal strip in simple graphics from the top left to the bottom right but when I put this into my code:

```
 if y> 1/2*x + 20 and y < 1\2*x - 20:
        return('yellow')
```

it returns SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using a `\\` instead of a `/`.

Comment: Oh.. silly me. Thank you!